# Joining hundreds of tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

What is the most performant way to join 238 tables in mysql that each contain a variable from a time serie. The client provided me with a csv file per time serie containing about 100k rows. I have loaded the data inside mysql but have no indexes until now.

I have tried to join 61 tables (the Max number in mysql ) but that was an epic fail. After 6 days an electrity disruption ended it, but untill then i had no results. I also tried to do it with an update but this also failed

Thank you for your advice

Comment: If you're trying to join 238 tables, then there's probably something wrong with the way you're organizing your data.

Comment: You have control over the table structure? Can you combine them into _one_ table that has an extra column identifying its source file (time series)?

Comment: What are You trying to achieve? Maybe using SQL database isn't the best way to do it (whatever it is).

Comment: But we can only speculate. Please provide the structure of the tables, and a small data sample from ~3 of them, plus a sample of what kind of output you want your queries to produce. Then we can help you organize it.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have control over this.

Comment: I dont know what is the use case . Companies like google can't afford joining data like this as it affects their performance - Hence Big Data . Relational DB is a mess just like when you have lots of relatives (No Puns :) ) . Keep It Simple .

Comment: I have to make a multivariate time serie model from machine data in which every sensor delivers a csv file ones a month

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having multiple tables of the same format is generally a bad idea in a well-designed database.  You should simply place all the data into one table and use that for your queries.  You can do this with an `insert` or `create table as` statement:

```
create table AllSeries as
    select 'series001' as SeriesName, s.* from series1 s union all
    select 'series002' as SeriesName, s.* from series2 s union all
    . . .
    select 'series0060' as SeriesName, s.* from series1 s;

insert into AllSeries
    select 'series061' as SeriesName, s.* from series1 s union all
    select 'series062' as SeriesName, s.* from series2 s union all
    . . .
    select 'series119' as SeriesName, s.* from series1 s;

/* and so on */
```

You should then add indexes to the table for performance, probably something like:

```
create index idx_AllSeries_SeriesName_Time on AllSeries(SeriesName, Time);
```

Your resulting queries should be much easier to write and perform better.

Comment: Thank you gordon. Union all is indeed an option followed by a transpose because i need the data as input for a mutlivariate model. This should work fine.

Comment: The limit on 63 table references per query also affects UNION. So this will take at least four queries to load all the data into one table.